# Рандомное врашение квадрата на JQuery

Tags: jquery, анимация

Привет, мне нужно сделать на HTML странице кнопку и прямоугольник . При нажатии на кнопку прямоугольник должен будет вращаться, каждый щелчок будет вращать прямоугольник случайным углом. Анимация вращения должна длится 300ms. Подскажите, пожалуйста с чего начать, что да как. Сделать все это надо при помши JQuery.

Comment: 1) сделать прямоугольник, 2) добавить кнопку 3) написать обработчик клика  4) посмотреть справку по css - transform 5) посмотреть справку по jquery animate

Comment: Пользовательская анимация на jquery [ссылка](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) Библиотека jQueryRotate [ссылка на описание](http://xiper.net/collect/js-plugins/effects/jqueryrotate) и [демо](http://www.xiper.net/examples/js-plugins/effects/jqueryrotate/index.html)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#but').on('click', function() {
    var deg = Math.random() * (180 - 30) + 30;
    $('#div').animate({
      borderSpacing: deg
    }, {
      step: function(now, fx) {
        $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
        $(this).css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
        $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
      },
      duration: 'slow'
    }, 'linear');
  });
});
```

```css
#div {
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Вращать" id="but">
<div id="div"></div>
```